# I have not accessed my Iota wallet for over two years. My seed is 80 characters long. What should I do to access my funds?

Tags: wallet, seed

I have not accessed my Iota for over two years. My seed is 80 characters long and the new trinity wallet only accepts 81 characters. what should I do to access my Iota please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert your seed and add the number 9 at the end to reach 81 characters.

Comment: Thank you good sir!